# How to disable LogCat pause completly?

Tags: android, logcat

I have a big problem with new LogCat and it's pause functionality. I like the idea to pause the output, when I want to read some older entries from it.

But there are also times when I want output to flow uninterrupted, so I can touch the phone, and see how it reacts through reading the output. So it is very frustrating to me, that LogCat pauses completely very often (the pause button is getting "pressed" automatically). I then have to unpause it using mouse or scrolling up and down in LogCat window, then it pauses again after just a few seconds. It annoys the hell out of me. Why does it happen? It happened with adt 15 and it is happening now with adt 17 (I skipped 16).

I'm using eclipse 3.7 indygo under xubuntu 10.4 (don't think that matters, but maybe it is).

Any of you experiencing the same problems with newer LogCat? Any idea how to solve it?

cheers,
kajman

Answer (score 0):

I noticed it pauses when you scroll the logcat window up, but doesn't unpause when you scroll it back to the bottom. (You have to unpause it manually then.)

Took me a while to figure that out. Not sure if it helps with your specific problem though.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not it. It happens to me without me doing anything (apart from interacting with phone). I think, I'll just use 'adb logcat' in some cases, but I'll surely miss some features like dynamic filtering or changing debug level.