# Turn off line breaking in logcat in adt 20

Tags: android, logcat

Is there a way to disable line breaking in the newest logcat (ADT 20)? Stack traces are a pain to read now.

Logcat just gets worse and worse with updates - first [pause issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928453/how-to-disable-logcat-pause-completly) now this.

Comment: dude... I gave up on logcat years ago. Just use `adb logcat` from the command line :P

Comment: i'll try to use [logcat-color](https://github.com/marshall/logcat-color). I't looks nice, no pause issues, can turn line wrapping off and so on. Looks like a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the deprecated old version of Logcat, if you want. You can launch the same in eclipse using following path,

Window --> Show View --> Other --> Android --> LogCat (deprecated)

Comment: I just didn't upgrade from adt 19 yet (but my colleagues did). I'll keep that in mind when transition would be needed or brings some nice features. Thanks!